# when click on the hyperlink it will going to browser ,so my reqirement is open in in_app ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink, xcode6, uitextview

Textview  having text  and  hyperlinks ,when  click  on the hyperlink it will going  to  browser ,so my requirement  is  open  in  in_app  i.e  web  View

Comment: ChckMark textview property : Detection > Link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegate `shouldInteractWithURL:` of `UITextView` to open in-app.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
    // your code to open locally "in-app"

    return NO;
}
```